# python3 inspect python2 module and vice versa

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, inspect

I need to find all classes and their methods(with arguments/signature) in a .py file.
There are some restrictions:

1. Should work under python2 and python3(the files to be scanned are python2).
2. The files are not in python/system path and module dependencies may be not satisfied (import may fail)

As far as I understand such modules like `ast`, `inspect`, `pyclbr` can not be used here for the reasons given above(different python versions etc).

What else can be helpful expect of `re` module?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there haven't been any major changes to classes/functions/modules (in regards to what you want to find), and thus either of the Python 2 or Python 3 `inspect` modules should do the job.

Comment: Can not be done with regex.  Python can generate classes/methods dynamically.  I think `ast` module will be ok ... your reasons for discounting them don't make sense?

Comment: You can use separate grammars for Python 2 and Python 3 and use a parser generator to create your own parser.  For a good example of this take a look at the code for lib2to3.  The Python source code contains a text file describing the grammar for the version you're looking at.  Do not try to use regular expressions to implement a parser for Python.  It will not work.

Comment: Regarding `ast`. It fails to parse python2 module from python3. For example, parsing this [module](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/source/browse/src/robot/libraries/BuiltIn.py) from python3 fails with error: `File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 637
    first, second = [self._convert_to_string(i) for i in first, second]
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Regarding `inspect`. It requires the module to be imported, as it 'inspects live objects', am I right? In my case, I cannot import the module to be inspected. The import statement fails because of issues like: ```>>> import BuiltIn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "BuiltIn.py", line 20, in <module>
    from robot.api import logger
ImportError: No module named robot.api```